# how to use dom4j SAXReader offline?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I would like to work with SAXReader **offline**, the problem is that SAXReader is verifying the xml accoerding to the DTD. I don't want to change the DTD or anything else in the XML. From searching on this website and other sources I found 2 answers that **did not** help me:

1. use EntityResolver to bypass the network call
2. use setIncludeExternalDTDDeclarations(false)

Example of what I tried to do:

```
protected Document getPlistDocument() throws MalformedURLException,
DocumentException {
    SAXReader saxReader = new SAXReader();
    saxReader.setIgnoreComments(false);
    saxReader.setIncludeExternalDTDDeclarations(false);
    saxReader.setIncludeInternalDTDDeclarations(true);
    saxReader.setEntityResolver(new MyResolver());
    Document plistDocument = saxReader.read(getDestinationFile().toURI().toURL());
    return plistDocument;
}

public class MyResolver implements EntityResolver {
    public InputSource resolveEntity (String publicId, String systemId)
    {
        if (systemId.equals("http://www.myhost.com/today")) {
            // if we want a custom implementation, return a special input source
            return null;

        } else {
            // use the default behaviour
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
```

I'm still unable to work offline, please advice... thanks

**StackTrace:**

```
14:20:44,358 ERROR [ApplicationBuilder] iphone build failed: Resource Manager - Problem handle Root.plist: www.apple.com Nested exception: www.apple.com
com.something.builder.sourcemanager.exception.SourceHandlingException: Resource Manager - Problem handle Root.plist: www.apple.com Nested exception: www.apple.com
****
****
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.apple.com Nested exception: www.apple.com
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:291)  
... 10 more
```

Comment: What's the error you are finding? Does it throw any exception? Could you post the message and stack trace of such exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your entity resolver doesn't handle anything (since it always returns null). Make it return an InputSource to the actual DTD file when the system ID is `http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd`, since that's the DTD that dom4j tries downloading.

```
public class MyResolver implements EntityResolver {
    public InputSource resolveEntity (String publicId, String systemId)
    {
        if (systemId.equals("http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd")) {
            return new InputSource(MyResolver.class.getResourceAsStream("/dtds/PropertyList-1.0.dtd");
        } else {
            // use the default behaviour
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation, for example, returns the DTD from the classpath (in the package `dtds`). You just have to download the DTD yourself and bundle it in your app, in the package `dtds`.

Answer (score 0):

Note, too, that you're not actually validating against the DTD. To accomplish that, you need to do:

```
SAXReader saxReader = new SAXReader(true);
```

Otherwise JB's right - he got in 3 mins before me!

Answer (score 0):

As an option, if you want to just use SAXReader offline, disable its external DTD fetching via the `http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd` Xerces
feature.

According [Xerces features documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html), setting this to **false** makes SAXReader ignore the external DTD completely.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856503/662728) has a code example.

Answer (score -1):

I use NoOpEntityResolver disable online dtd, see code in this website: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#no-op-entityresolver