# javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: xslt, https, doctype, dtd

I am trying to transform a xml using XSLT. My xml has "https" url of dtd file in xml doctype. If I remove this doctype I could able to transform the file but with the doctype I am getting below error.

```
ERROR:  'Connection timed out: connect'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:719)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    at Example.main(Example.java:59)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:709)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:446)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:524)
    ... 3 more
---------
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:709)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    at Example.main(Example.java:59)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:446)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:524)
    ... 3 more
---------
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:446)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:524)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:709)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    at Example.main(Example.java:59)
---------
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
```

I could not remove this doctype in live scenario. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're are getting the error because the parser is going out to the Web to resolve the DTD at the url in the DOCTYPE. This fetch is failing.

You need to store the DTD locally and use an EntityResolver to use the local copy instead.

See this question and top answer to see how to do that. [Prevent DTD download when using XSLT i.e. XML Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091384/prevent-dtd-download-when-using-xslt-i-e-xml-transformer)

Comment: Thanks @Alohci , It is working but anyhow can we ignore the dtd download and validation ? In my live scenario I can receive multiple kind of XML and I could not keep and track the dtd for all xml locally.

Comment: If you get the entityResolver to return the empty string when it matches that url, then effectively no validation will be done and you don't have to keep a copy of the DTD locally. If there are any entities defined in the DTD, you'll lose that information though, obviously.